# Android TableLayout Width

Tags: android, layout, width, tablelayout

I have a two column `TableLayout` as the only child of a scroll view. The first column contains `TextViews` ('labels') and the second column contains `EditText`/`Spinner`/`DateWidget` etc ('values'). Even though I have have specified `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` for `TableLayout`, `TableRow` & all widgets (in 'values' column).

The screen looks perfect when the activity is created. However, when one types a really long value in the `EditText`, the 'values' column goes beyond the visible screen area.

How do I tackle this?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You may want to define the sizes of the columns by using a weight. So you will define the table layout height to fill parent but for each column you should set the width to "0px" and the weight to the percentage you want the column to span. So assuming you want the first column to be 30% of the screen width you set it's weight to "0.3" and the second column to "0.7".

Try it and see if that works.

Comment: This was the only thing that finally did it for me. Just a note as well that if you have shrinkColumns or stretchColumns set on TableLayout then that can have an adverse affect on everything.

Comment: This answer isn't clear to me, you mean setting the weights on all the children of all the TableRow groups? If so what is the point of using a TableLayout at all? Why Not just use LinearLayouts? I suggest setting both stretch and shrink on the column that is giving you trouble.

Answer (score 29):

The pragmatic way to solve this is to use the `stretchColumns` and `shrinkColumns` attributes in `TableLayout`. Their values should be 0-based indexes of columns.

For example, if you have a two column Table layout and:

- You would like the second column to fill up with empty space (stretch) so the `TableLayout` fits the entire parent view on a large screen device
- You would like the first column to be shrunk (and its contents possibly wrapped / ellipsized) on a small screen device

you would define your `TableLayout` as:

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/my_table_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="1"
    android:shrinkColumns="0" >
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Also note that you can both stretch and shrink a column. Doing that on my TextView column prevents it from going beyond the screen size but also allows it to fill up the available space.

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me..

```
tableLayout.setColumnShrinkable(1,true);
```

Comment: Awesome! first param is the column, and second to set it shrinkable! Thanx!

Comment: good, this work for me too. I use you setColumnShrinkable and setColumnStretchable for play with table behavior.

Answer (score 6):

```
<TableLayout 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp">
<TableRow 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent">
<TextView 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:text="Name " 
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</TextView>
<EditText 
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:hint="name"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
>
</EditText>
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

This code worked for me to align text view on first column and edit text fill parent.

Comment: This approach helps a lot when your cells need different sizes from row to row

Answer (score 0):

Try this, make sure `android:singleLine="false"` and `android:inputType="textMultiLine"`:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1">
    <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">

        <TextView android:text="Label:" />
        <EditText android:id="@+id/entry" android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="false" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with EditText on Android 2.2. In my case adding android:maxWidth="0sp" property helped. Now EditText field is displayed as I wanted - so it is still of the same size as other EditText fields, but additionaly it is not resized when long text is entered.

Here is my EditText definition:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/extra_edit"
       android:padding="3dip"
       android:inputType="textImeMultiLine"
       android:maxWidth="0sp"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       />
```

Comment: The hint and value in the EditText get distorted -- I can see only the first letter. Any work arounds?

Comment: Note even though this is old: if you are using a 0 value, consider just using 0px. sp means that Android will apply a scaling value to it, and 0 * anything = 0

Answer (score 0):

***It works for me, hope this helps to you as well***

Iam looping 3 times so 3 rows will add,added picture below

```
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(getActivity());
    tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,2));
    tr.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

    TextView labelText = new TextView(getActivity());

    labelText.setText(key + " ");
    labelText.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,0.7f));
    labelText.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
    labelText.setTextSize(8);
    labelText.setPadding(5, 0, 5, 0);
    tr.addView(labelText);

    View seperatorView = new View(getActivity());
    seperatorView.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(2, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    seperatorView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.radio_border_color));
    tr.addView(seperatorView);

    TextView valueText = new TextView(getActivity());
    valueText.setText(value);
    valueText.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.3f));
    valueText.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
   
    valueText.setTextSize(8);
    
    valueText.setMinLines(1);
    valueText.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    valueText.setPadding(5, 0, 5, 0);
    tr.addView(valueText);

    barcodeTableLayout.addView(tr);
```

[image]