# Table Layout Spacing issue

Tags: android, xml, android-tablelayout

I have a scroll view Table Layout. It has 2 columns. One of them (first) is a description and the second is an amount. I have made it such that the First column can WRAP text if necessary. 
My problem now is to restrict the WIDTH of both the columns, so that they are 50-50% in the screen. and the first column should wrap. I did try to use android:minWidth="215dp" , but i dont want to hard code my values in the xml.

Here is the xml. Any help is appreciated.

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tableheader"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="none" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/dataTable"
        style="@style/SummaryTableLayout" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:gravity="left"
            android:minWidth="215dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:gravity="left"
            android:minWidth="215dp"
                    />

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The SummaryTableLayout Style part is

```
<style name="SummaryTableLayout" >
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:stretchColumns">0</item>
    <item name="android:shrinkColumns">0</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">25dp</item>
    <item name="android:scrollbars">vertical</item>
    <item name="android:isScrollContainer">true</item>
    <item name="android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack">true</item>
</style>
```

EDIT ::: this is one of my xmls. I have a second xml, where the table layout has 4 columns, i would like those to be evenly spaced as well with the first column having WRAPPING.

Comment: Try to set equal weight to both textviews

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `layout_weigth` attribute. This should work for you:

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/dataTable"
    style="@style/SummaryTableLayout" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:gravity="left"
        android:width="0px"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"/>

    <TextView
        android:gravity="left"
        android:width="0px"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"/>

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

As per this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4059010/1108032) . `layout_weight` is used to define the percantages of the columns.

**EDIT** Please note I substituted `layout_width` with `width` for the columns as it seems this is the correct attribute to use in this case.

Comment: He probably wants to make the columns to take 50% of the screen only for the case when the first `TextView`'s text isn't smaller that half the screen.

Comment: @Luksprog: I might have misunderstood him, but I, myself, would rather have fixed layout, than changing column widths based on the contents.

Comment: I agree with your opinion, I've just made a small observation.