# TableRow heights getting blown out

Tags: android, imageview, tablelayout, tablerow

I have a TableLayout with 3 TableRows, each TableRow has 3 ImageViews. Each ImageView has fitCenter for Scale type, and a weight and width per this stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865497/xml-table-layout-two-equal-width-rows-filled-with-equally-width-buttons/2865558#2865558). Now all the images scale to fit into the row, but each row is way taller then it needs to be. Here's an excerpt of the xml:

```
<TableLayout android:id="@+id/TableLayout01"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="10dip"
android:stretchColumns="0,1,2"
android:shrinkColumns="0,1,2"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content">
    <TableRow android:id="@+id/TableRow01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:src="@drawable/avocado3"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/image2"
        android:src="@drawable/avocado3"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/image3"
        android:src="@drawable/avocado3"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
    </TableRow>
...
</TableLayout>
```

And here's the first row:

[image: first row]

And the end of the first row and start of the second:

[image: second row]

The ImageViews are set to a drawable that is small (@drawable/avocado3), and in the activity's onCreate() it fetches 9 images from the internet and calls setImageBitmap().

Anyone have any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `scaleType` only changes the size of the actual image, but not the size of the surrounding `ImageView`. Since the height of the `ImageView` is set to `wrap_content`, it will take all the space it needs to display the full image, and then scale the image to fit it inside it's width.

Try setting `adjustViewBounds` to true. If that doesn't help, try setting a fixed `layout_height` or play around with the `maxHeight` property.

It might also help to take a look inside the hierarchy viewer: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/hierarchy-viewer.html.

Comment: Sweet! adjustViewBounds did it! Thanks a lot. I had just done some other work to scale the images before calling setImageBitmap(); time to take that hack out.