# 2 buttons side by side

Tags: android, user-interface, layout

How can I put 2 buttons side by side, so that they occupy all the width, with a little space between them?

I thought a horiz linear layout, with 2 sub linear layouts set to match parent and weight 1, each of them containing the button. Is there a simpler way? can this be accomplished with relative layouts?

Comment: you can try tablelayout,two buttons be put into tabrow,i think this meet you

Comment: This can be more complex what the question suggest.. since you have to add table layout then after table row then add two buttons.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XML Table layout? Two EQUAL-width rows filled with equally width buttons??](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865497/xml-table-layout-two-equal-width-rows-filled-with-equally-width-buttons)

Comment: dear no need to give orientation just give the padding to button and orientation is by default is horizontal which you require in your application...try it hope it work..

Comment: if the problem is not solved check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14892365/linear-layout-with-two-buttons-side-by-side-android

Answer (score 125, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/Button02" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="1" android:text="Apply">
    </Button>
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/Button03" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:text="Cancel">
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That's the first thing I tried, but I got a compiler error trying to apply the layout_weight on buttons.. maybe something else was wrong.. I'll try that again

Comment: that surprises me, i use this code for 1,6 to 2.3 without any problems

Comment: layout_alignParentBottom (line 5) is invalid for LinearLayout.

Comment: you're right, but in my Code is the LL a Child of a RelativeLayout, then th LL is shown at the Bottom of the RL

Comment: This doesn't work. The buttons in this example are of similar width only because the text inside is of similar length. Try using text of radically different length (I'm using "Downloaded" and "All") and have a look at the effect.

Answer (score 5):

If you want that the 2 buttons ocuppy all the width and the buttons have the same width, you must change in the 2 buttons the propertie:

`android:layout_width="wrap_content"` to `android:layout_width="match_parent"`

because if  you have one of this button with a long text and the other button with short text, the button with long text ocuppy more space.

Answer (score 5):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:text="button1"
    android:id="@+id/button" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:text="button2"
    android:id="@+id/button2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using LinearLayout, for each button: make the width match_parent, and the `weight="1"`.  The margin will provide a little space in between each button.  With this, you can add as many buttons in a row as you want, all with similar width.

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this,

Make a `RelaiveLayout` `orientation` as `horizontal` and the give some `padding` to have a space between them..

Make the `Layoutheight` and `Layoutwidth` of ur wish

Thanks

Comment: Orientation is a property of LinearLayout, not RelativeLayout. Even though I don't think it throws a compiler error, it doesn't actually have any effect.