# Set equal width of columns in table layout in Android

Tags: android, tablelayout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XML Table layout? Two EQUAL-width rows filled with equally width buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865497/xml-table-layout-two-equal-width-rows-filled-with-equally-width-buttons)

I am using `TableLayout` to show list of data in 4 columns.

***Problem description:***

I am unable to set equal width of all 4 columns, which are in my `TableLayout`. 
I am putting my layout code, which I am using...

```
<TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:stretchColumns="0">
        <TableRow>
            <TextView android:text="table header1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                 android:textSize="10dip" android:textStyle="bold"/>    
            <TextView android:text="table header2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:textSize="10dip" android:textStyle="bold"/> 
            <TextView android:text="table header3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:textSize="10dip" android:textStyle="bold"/> 
            <TextView android:text="table header4" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:textSize="10dip" android:textStyle="bold"/>         
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

*How should I rewrite this layout to show 4 columns with equal sizes?*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2865497/778427

Answer (score 220, accepted):

[Try this.](http://androidadvice.blogspot.com/2010/10/tablelayout-columns-equal-width.html)

It boils down to adding `android:stretchColumns="*"` to your `TableLayout` root and setting `android:layout_width="0dp"` to all the children in your `TableRow`s.

```
<TableLayout
    android:stretchColumns="*"   // Optionally use numbered list "0,1,2,3,..."
>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="0dp"
    >
```

Comment: Just a little note... I also had to add `android:layout_weight="1"` to the children of `TableRows` for it to work.

Comment: stretchColumns should be "*", not 1 to have all columns be of equal width.

Comment: This solution works for me, but I was looking for at way to do it programmatically. I used `setStretchAllColumns(true)` on `TableLayout` and `setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT))` on each `TableRow` child. Setting weight didn't seem to be necessary.

Comment: @Sherif elKhatib your solution works but when we set each column width by wrap_content. If the column data increased the column width will be increased as well and the columns will not be from the same size at this point.

Do you have solution for this ?

Can we set max_width for each column to be the equal desired width ?

Answer (score 77):

Change `android:stretchColumns` value to `*`.

Value `0` means stretch the first column. Value `1` means stretch the second column and so on.

Value `*` means stretch all the columns.

Comment: Its not working, if column1 is text is more, its expanding.

Comment: Yep, this is not working

Comment: Just remove your android:stretchColumns="0" and add android:layout_weight="1" to all four and you get the desired output.

Comment: Don't forget to add android:layout_width="0dp", or weights won't be taken into account.

Comment: thanks its working like charm