# how to create three columns in TableLayout

Tags: android, layout

I am developing a screen that uses `TableLayout`. Here I am easily able to create two columns. but how can I create three columns ?

Comment: add another column exactly in the same way as you did for adding two columns

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here an example:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1">
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:text="first"
            android:padding="3dip" />
        <TextView
            android:text="second"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="3dip" />
        <TextView
            android:text="third"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="3dip" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:text="first"
            android:padding="3dip" />
        <TextView
            android:text="second"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="3dip" />
        <TextView
            android:text="third"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="3dip" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: @Lucifer i think you should upvote to their effort also if you found their answer helpful.

Comment: To have a fixed equal width for all columns, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6647298/261436

Answer (score 2):

For each TableRow you have to add three children instead of two. This should be ok for you!

Hope this helps!