# Change the existing width of the button to at maximum 1/3 of the screen

Tags: android

How to change the existing width of a button programmatically to 1/3 of the width of the screen at maximum. By saying ‘at maximum’ I mean that if there will be enough space for a button to be 1/3 of the screen it should be resized. Otherwise the button should fit in the existing space gap (it can be for example 1/4 or even 1/5 of the screen’s width).

EDIT:
I'm looking for a soultion for RelativeLayout.

Comment: Too long to be reasonable to post. Button is standard and on it’s left or right it can have other elements. I’m looking for a solution not only in current project. Every working solution for RelativeLayout is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html) with three columns, see this example for more details

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-tablelayout-example/

Comment: and this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616194/how-to-create-three-columns-in-tablelayout

Comment: I should be more precise - I’m trying to avoid TableLayout – I’m using RelativeLayout with many nested elements.

Comment: @Annabelle I suggest you update your question with some more details, including the layout you're using :)