# Android: change width in Table Layout using LayoutParams so the content can be fit

Tags: android, background-color, android-tablelayout, layoutparams

So I am creating a table that contains the texts that are very long with 4-5 columns, and what I need is the table that is able to WRAP content in each column (in width and height). I want all of my content can be seen. If the texts are long, the table can automatically makes the content to next line. (Right now, it still fills the whole emulator width, so other columns can't be seen)

Here is my current code at MainActivity.java:

```
int rows = c.getCount();
int cols = c.getColumnCount();

c.moveToFirst();

// outer for loop
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) 
{
TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

// inner for loop
for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) 
{
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
tv.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
tv.setTextSize(10);
tv.setPadding(0, 5, 0, 5);
tv.setText(c.getString(j));

row.addView(tv);                
}
c.moveToNext();
mytable.addView(row);
```

}

what I want if the text is long is like this:

```
id     description       name 
1000   the quick brown   John
       fox jumps over    Doe
       the dog
```

But my current one is like this

```
id     description       name 
1000   the quick brown fox jumps over the dog
```

name field can't be seen since the column 2's text is very long. Please help me with this matter. Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

You could try dividing the tablerow into equal parts
Link : [Set equal width of columns in table layout in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647177/set-equal-width-of-columns-in-table-layout-in-android)

You can set the textview width or the textview max witdh (setWidth(), setMaxWidth()), so your textview wil become multiline when it exedes the set width.