# Android - Equal column width layout for any size text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout, android-gridlayout

I'm quite new to android. I wanted to show cards in a tabular form. I want 2 columns which should be exactly equal in length (even if the size of the content in one of the column increases).

For example, it should be like **Play Store** or **Google Keep**. My card will have 2 lines of data. First for *Title* and second for *Description*.

[image]

I tried many layouts; `TableLayout`, `GridLayout` etc. but neither worked actually. Lastly I read [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647177/set-equal-width-of-columns-in-table-layout-in-android) but it doesn't work if text size on my card increases.

Any idea on how this can be done? It will be a bonus if the *Description* text ellipsizes at end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you well enough:

Try using a LinearLayout and setting the layout_weight of the items inside the layout. So you'll have something like:

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Card
        android:id="@+id/card1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Card
        android:id="@+id/card2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then if you wanted to perhaps have multiple things in the columns just make those card items additional LinearLayouts of vertical orientation.

Comment: This is working fine but what if I have only 1 card (or any odd number of cards) ?

Comment: Okay.. solved that issue by adding an empty `View`. This is working now. Thanks!